# Handlebars rendered in new line

Tags: ember.js

I'm implementing Google strctured data using Ember and adding some dynamic values

```html
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  [{
    "@context": "{{my-ember-hbs}}",
...
```

The rendered html is:

```html
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  [{
    "@context": "  // ember adds new line before and after
         rendered-value-string
   ",
...
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproduction using Ember Twiddle or CodeSandbox?

Comment: its not a new line, its a seperate `TextNode`.

Comment: How do I do then to eliminate the supposed "\n" ?

Answer (score 1):

According the the [Handlebars docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) you can eliminate white space with a tilde `~`.

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  [{
    "@context": "{{~my-ember-hbs~}}",
...
```

`{{my-ember-hbs}}` may also have white space internally that you would need to account for.